# How can I prevent jQuery slideUp until form is filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am having some trouble with jQuery overriding my form, I set my inputs to required but when i click on the submit with empty inputs, jQuery will still initiate the slideup animation. Is there a way around this?

Thanks!

```
    //form slide
    $("#button").click(function () {
    $("#main-form").slideUp("slow");
    });

    $("#slide-down").click(function () {
    $("#main-form").slideDown("slow");
    });

    //hide arrow
    $("#slide-down").hide();

   //show arrow on submit
   $("#button").click(function () {
   $("#slide-down").fadeIn(500);
   });
```

Comment: Thats because you are telling it to slide up when you click the button. You need to verify that the form fields have been filled in before submitting and sliding up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want your animations to take place on submit, not on button click. Change your listener to something like this:

```
$("form").on("submit", function(){
 // Your animation goes here
})
```

Modern browsers should detect missing required input and prevent form submission.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you. That was something that totally went over my head.